# I read image file as binary strange symbols appear

Tags: python, binary, hex, binary-data

I read an image file in binary in python:

`open('chall.png, 'rb').read()`

Result:

```
b'\xe0>8.~cxfein{ ;-0lek\xf7virejneinv\xe7I\x01blo7\x14"1\x07;\x03\x1bE\x19\x1c\x19\x0f\x1a\x05\x07L\x11\x10\x1e\x13I\x16\x11\x0b\nei\x16\xac\x84\xeb2\xf4O\xdcd*\x89\x1af7`e\xf7i\xd7j\xd7\x03\xe7\x15\x8c\x80\x92,$>L\x0f\xa4\xf2\x94\x98\xe9IE\x06@7\xb5\xfc |g\xe1{\xbf\x11\x93\x94\x1e\x11\x88\xaf8\x13\xcb#\x08\xbf\x1b\xdeO-\x1c\xb6M\xf6FS\xcb6\x9c\n,\x99\x90\x90\x14\xfb\xf8\x97\x1a\x94\xcb\x
```

*(the binary code of the file is larger than this)*

Wait what ? Binary is a lot of 1's and 0's. Okay, perhaps this is hexadecimal (a format that makes binary more readable for humans) ?

Nope, this is certainly not hexadecimals either! What is going on ?

What am I dealing with here ?

How can I convert it into hexadecimals or something more readable than this ? (as you might guess I am quite new to this. Please be nice.)

---

EDIT:

```
file = open('image.png', 'rb').read()
file[0]
#output: 224
file[1]
#output: 62
```

How come the output of the first "character" (the first index) be 224? Shouldn't it be `\xe0`?

Answer (score 0):

When you read a binary data and try to print it, the binary data is tried and decoded into `utf-8` by default. Thats why you see strange characters. The below code formats as hex before printing. You should see hexadecimals data with out any stage characters using the below code.

```
for i in open('image.png', 'rb').read():
    print(r'{0:#x}'.format(i), end=' ')
```

Comment: I know what hexadecimal is. Is HEX=hexadecimals?

Comment: Is it possible to avoid having python by default try and convert the binary into utf-8? I mean, can't I just "read it" as binary?

Comment: You mean you want ones and zeros? Can you please elaborate more on your exact expectation. Edit it in the main question. If possible, also provide why you want as binary.